# Git working over http but not ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I have a remote repository that is working fine when I communicate over http, but if I use ssh it gives me errors when trying to push.

#### Goal: get the repo to work over ssh

I can ssh directly into the remote machine without problem, all folders and files in the git repo and git working directory have 771 permissions, the owner is apache and group is 'test' (which the user I'm ssh-ing with 'test' is a member of).  I also tried changing the owner and group to 'test', but that didn't help.  I've confirmed the user account is able to read/write/execute from the git directories via ssh.

I have a non-standard directory setup due to using virtualmin:
/home/test  (user home)
/home/test/public_html  (web root)
/home/test/public_html/git   (gitweb directory)
/home/test/public_html/git/git.git    (repo directory)

This causes the same error message as below (no such file or directory) when I do any git commands 'locally' (directly on the remote server) unless I specify --git-dir and --work-tree, however, since http is working and pushing to the remote server shouldn't need to know the remote working directory, I don't see how this would be the issue (and also don't see how to fix it if it was).

Also, if it's relevant, I'm using password authentication rather than keys.

Does anyone have thoughts on how I can solve / further diagnose this issue?

#### The error

git push origin:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 309 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename ./objects/1d: No such file or directory

fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To test@test.local:/home/test/public_html/git/git.git/
! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'test@test.local:/home/test/public_html/git/git.git/'
```

#### More info

git push origin (WHEN USING HTTP to http://test@test.local/git/git.git/):

```
Password: 
Password: 
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/heads/
  refs/tags/
updating 'refs/heads/master'
  from 425f5c3810b1c9e4ecc7ee7df3cd1bb8818b2115
  to   65d2358df3035689116339a14f504f34a6212a27
    sending 3 objects
    done
Updating remote server info
To http://test@test.local/git/git.git/
   425f5c3..65d2358  master -> master
```

*(I'm a bit confused why there's so much difference between http and ssh here; the http asks me my password twice and then starts fetching remote heads, whereas the ssh asks me my password once and then starts counting objects.)*

git pull origin:

```
Already up-to-date
```

git remote show origin:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: test@test.local:/home/test/public_html/git/git.git/
  Push  URL: test@test.local:/home/test/public_html/git/git.git/
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master  tracked
    release tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master  merges with remote master
    release merges with remote release
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master  pushes to master  (fast-forwardable)
    release pushes to release (up to date)
```

And if it's of any use, my local config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = test@test.local:/home/test/public_html/git/git.git/
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin 
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "release"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/release
```

And remote config file:

```
[core] 
   repositoryformatversion = 0
   filemode = true
   bare = false
   worktree = /home/test/public_html
   sharedRepository = true
```

---

**Further investigation**

After Jan's comments I investigated the problem a bit further.  I was assuming only the 'test' account would be used during push over ssh (and apache used over http push), but I think it must be both.  
I've gone back through the non-working repo and set the ownership the same as in the working repo (some files/folders are apache.test, others are test.test, and the config file is root.test).  
I haven't checked absolutely everything, but the files in the repo dir, and all files and folders under objects, refs and info all have identical ownership and permissions in both the working and non-working, and the user accounts are set up in the same way (I did try 777 in my troubleshooting previously).
The main difference I can think of is that in the the non-working repo, I started using http and then switched to ssh, whereas in the working repo I went directly to using ssh and the repo was empty before that.  Perhaps there's an odd file somewhere with wrong permissions that's breaking everything, or there's something bizarre going on inside the actual files that I've upset by using different protocols, or maybe it's just got corrupt due to my hours of trying to get it to work yesterday.

Comment: Your directory structure given at the beginning of the question contradicts your shown command output (`/home/test/public_html/git/git.git` vs `/home/test/git.git`)

Comment: Ack, sorry, typo in my given structure!  I'll fix.

Comment: I've added info for what happens when I push over http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a brand new remote repository under a different user account and it's now working fine.  All settings are the more or less the same (permissions are less strict this time), so I'm not sure what the issue was.

Comment: As it was almost certainly permissions problem, less strict permissions may well deal with it. Also the problem happens only the push via one channel created something and the push via the other wants to use it, so on a new repo it may take some time to manifest.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant more strict with the working repo.  I think ownership may be the key.  I'm putting further investigation details into the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you search the web for the exact text of the error message you are getting, it returns lots of hits. From quick look at them, it seems to be a permission problem.

You say you have the repository owned by `apache.test`. However, is apache actually running as `apache.test`? If not, the new directories the git server run by apache create will be owned by different group (whatever is primary group of the server) and the `test` user can't write there despite the fact you told git to make the repo group-writable.

You have several options:

1. Use [suExec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) to run the git cgi as `test.test` and drop the group-writable permission.
2. Use the primary group of the web server as the owning group
3. Make the repo everybody-writable (`core.sharedRepository` = `everybody`)
4. It should be possible to make the repo SGID to the right group by setting `core.sharedRepository` to `2664`, but I am not too sure with that.

Personally I'd prefer the suExec.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Jan, that got me thinking about the accounts used during the process.  I've done some more investigation and will put the details in the original questions.